# Perform a flash (light) like the native camera app does

Tags: ios, objective-c, flash

How can i perform a flash like the native camera app performs one?
I've found the following code to turn on the light, but i need to take a flash-shot.

```
if(self.videoDevice.hasTorch) {
    [self.videoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [self.videoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel: 1.0 error: nil];
    [self.videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set torchLevel between 0.0 to 1.0 and then again to 0.0 for a very small interval.

```
- (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError
```

Comment: That was my thought too, but i think the whole mechanism is a more complex than it seems to bee as everything needs to be timed in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Seems like same thing you are expecting

http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/flashlight-application-using-the-iphone-led.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (void)turnOnCamerFlash
{
    if (NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice") != nil)
    {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        if ([device hasTorch])
        {
            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: This just turns on the flash-light, but i need to simulate something like the native flash :)

Answer (score 0):

It seams that there is no flash-function in there, so the (only?) possibility to perform a flash is to use a timer.

```
    - (IBAction)doFlash:(id)sender {
        if(self.videoDevice.hasTorch) {
            flashCounter = 0;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(flashLightTicker:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats: YES];
        }
    }

    - (void)flashLightTicker:(id)sender {
        [self.videoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(flashCounter == 0) {
            [self.videoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel: 0.1 error: nil];
        }
        if(flashCounter == 5) {
            [self.videoDevice setTorchMode: AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        }
        if(flashCounter == 7) {
            [self.videoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel: AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel error: nil];
        }
        if(flashCounter >= 10) {
            [self.videoDevice setTorchMode: AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [sender invalidate];
        }
        [self.videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        flashCounter++;
    }
```